# How to make an automatic interchange for 3 processes with a mutex?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I have 3 programs, each of them need to write 1000 times in one file. Mutex must switch programs after every 10 writings

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
HANDLE ghMutex;


void write()
{
    ghMutex = OpenMutex(SYNCHRONIZE, false, (LPTSTR)"WriteData");
    for (int i=0; i<100; i ++) { 
            WaitForSingleObject(ghMutex, INFINITE);
            ofstream f1("c:\\write.txt", ios_base::app);
            for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
                    f1 << 2;        
            ReleaseMutex(ghMutex);
            f1.close();
            Sleep(100);
    }
}

void main(){
write();
}
```

First program with "f1 << 1" and second with "f1 << 2"
They aren't synchronize, how to make it?
Help me to do it with 2 programs for beginning, please.

Comment: And you forgot to mention this is Homework & also your efforts to solve it.

Comment: I don't think it's homework; a professor would know (I hope!) that a mutex doesn't work like this.

Comment: @MSalters: doesn't mean students understand the concept as well as their professors ;-)

Comment: Do you wish for a specific execution ordering ? i.e. should p1 write, then p2, then p3, and so on ?

Comment: @ Jeandard Claboudin Does mutex allow it?

Comment: @user1173543: not as such. You will have to implement it yourself; there are several ways to do it. For instance, you could allocate one event per process, and each process would signal the event for the next process when it is done. Or you can use a variable in shared memory, coupled to an event to activate when the variable changes. You should post another question dealing specifically with that :)

Comment: I agree with @JeandardClaboudin that achieving a cooperative multi-process round-robin ordering on a pre-emptive multi-tasking operating system is another question of its own.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your descriptions exactly how you want your program to behave.  Do you want the program to guarantee that the processes alternate, if so, do you want a round-robin type ordering (e.g. process 1, then process 2, then process 3, then process 1 again)?

However, it's clear that your current mutex usage is incorrect.  First, at least one process must call `CreateMutex()` to actually create the mutex (or else there is no mutex to open).  Since the documentation for [`CreateMutex()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411.aspx) says:

> If `lpName` matches the name of an existing named mutex object, this function requests the `MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS` access right.

Assuming requesting more access is not a problem for you (it rarely is), then you can just have all instances call `CreateMutex()` ensuring that they all share the same mutex and whichever starts first actually creates is.

This is a simple example with processes that alternate in an unpredictable order (repeats are allowed), but correctly write to the file 10 times in a row without being interrupted by concurrent writers.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main ( int, char ** )
{
    // get a named mutex.  open the same mutex as other
    // concurrent instances.
    const ::HANDLE mutex = ::CreateMutexW(0, FALSE, L"Fubar");
    if (mutex == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        const ::DWORD error = ::GetLastError();
        std::cerr
            << "Could not open mutex (" << error << ")."
            << std::endl;
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // open the input file.  notice the flags, you need to make
    // sure the 2nd process doesn't overwrite whatver the first
    // wrote, etc.
    std::ofstream file("foo.txt", std::ios::app);
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr
            << "Could not open file."
            << std::endl;
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // wait for user to unblock after launch.  this gives time
    // to start concurrent processes before we write to the
    // file.
    ::getch();

    // not sure how your application goes, but lets just
    // repeatedly write to the file until we're fed up.
    for (int j=0; j < 100; ++j)
    {
        // lock the mutex around the code that writes to the
        // file in a loop.
        ::WaitForSingleObject(mutex, INFINITE);
        for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
            file << "process " << ::GetCurrentProcessId() << std::endl;
        }
        ::ReleaseMutex(mutex);

        // slow down so the application doesn't finish before we
        // unblock concurrent instances.
        ::Sleep(100);
    }

    // don't forget to clean up!
    ::CloseHandle(mutex);
}
```

Start multiple instances of this process (2 or more) and when all are launched, press a single key in each console window to have the processes start writing.  The output file will contain burts of 10 outputs for each process.

Comment: @ André Caron Thanks!!! It really works! Just answer please, can mutex do a round-robin type ordering?

Comment: @André: +1, you made up for my laziness :)

Comment: @user1173543: there's no way to achieve that with a single mutex.  You **might** be able to achieve a round-robin ordering with one mutex per process, where each process holds a lock on its own mutex and releases it when done writing.  If the successor (and only the correct successor) is waiting on that mutex, then you might achieve something like that.  However, that's a much more elaborate setup and might be a little complex for an example.  It is an exercise left to the reader ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Is `ghMutex` valid in any of the processes ? What about the value returned by `GetLastError()` after `OpenMutex()` and `WaitForSingleObject()` ?

You need to create the mutex in one of the processes before other processes can open it. Fortunately, `CreateMutex` does exactly what you need: it creates the mutex if it does not exist, and opens it it if does.

And you may want to close the stream before (not after) releasing the mutex, so that cached data is flushed before other processes start writing.

Comment: How to connect them? They're writing together. I think they don't see each other

Comment: @user1173543: just replace the call to `OpenMutex` by a call to `CreateMutex`. And check return values :-). You should also close the stream before releasing the mutex.

Comment: I rename to CreateMutex and close the stream before releasing. It's not help.