# How to make a round-robin type ordering in a mutex?

Tags: c++, windows, algorithm, multiprocessing

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ( int, char ** )
{
    HANDLE mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, L"PRV");

    for (int j=0; j < 100; ++j)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(mutex, INFINITE);

        ofstream file("c:\\write.txt", ios::app);
        for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
            file << 1;
        }
        ReleaseMutex(mutex);
        Sleep(100);
    }

    CloseHandle(mutex);
}
```

I create 4 pograms with `file << 1`...`file << 4` and they're works, but i need a round-robin type ordering. Or, at least, without a writing one process twice sequentially.

Comment: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9036076/1168156) to your previous question André has shown you how to synchronize processes by using name mutex, but are you sure it is what you want? I guess it would be much easier if you just create 4 threads within the same process.

Comment: @Artem: you may want to specify that the "programs" are actually separate processes. This will help people to offer more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve your goal with a single mutex, but you can fairly easily use two mutexes to make sure no one process ever writes twice in a sequence. What you need to do is to always have one process in a waiting queue and one process in a writing state. To do this you create two mutextes, let's call them `queueMutex` and `writeMutex`. The iteration logic in pseudo code should look like this:

```
acquire(queueMutex) // The process is next to write
acquire(writeMutex) // The process can now write
release(queueMutex) // Some other process can enter the queue

// now we can write 
write_to_file()

// Let's hold on here until some other process 
// enters the queue
// we do it by trying to acquire the queueMutex
// until the acquisition fails
while try_acquire(queueMutex)
    release(queueMutex)
    sleep

// try_acquire(queueMutex) finally failed
// this means some other process has entered the queue
// we can release the writeMutex and finish this iteration
release(writeMutex)
```

I will leave the implementation details up to you. When you implement the algorithm make sure you handle properly the last iteration for the last process, otherwise it will hang. Good luck!

Comment: I'm also pretty sure this approach can be extended to implement round-robin iteration for N processes with N mutexes. Just have a queue of mutexes and make sure each process moves through it by getting the next mutex, releasing the old one and then waiting to make sure the old mutex gets picked by another process before proceeding.